# How do I get form post in Nodejs app to work on cpanel

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

please I have a Node.js/Express application with a form in an html file. The form works fine on my local machine when I run it,This **form.html** is in a public folder, below is the form attributes which also has a submit button below;

```
<form action="/api/students" method="post" class="was-validated shadow font-weight-bold" >...
```

I also have the backend api in an **index.js** file which is in the same directory with the public folder as below,

```
...
// Serving static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

// Students API Routes
app.use('/api/students', require('./routes/students'));

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect( 
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
    {  useNewUrlParser: true ,
       useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    },
    () => console.log('Connected to DB')
);


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 2100;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

I tried to deploy it on a cpanel shared hosting platform which worked somehow **But** the form post can not be submitted and gives request time out error. I have tried to change the form action value as below but its not working.

```
<form action="my_domain_name.com/api/students" method="post" class="was-validated shadow font-weight-bold" >...
```

```
<form action="my_domain_name.com:2100/api/students" method="post" class="was-validated shadow font-weight-bold" >...
```

Please can someone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Node.js Express API can not be reached.

How are you hosting the Node app on the cpanel? It sounds like you just uploaded all the static html files to the host, but are not running the node app - hence why the request is timing out.

Comment: I hosted it using nodejs app setup in cpanel. Any idea as to how to go about it?

Comment: are you able to send a request to the api using something like https://www.postman.comit - might be a problem with your domain and making sure the data is actually flowing there first

Comment: Yes, I am able to send request to the api from my app and with postman on my local environment. The problem is that its not working on cpanel.